# how to check if a variable is not null and print it - batch file

Tags: batch-file

sometimes the ping fails and returns " " ,  i need to skip that empty line and if it's not empty print it
and count how many pings were successful

```
@echo off
for /l %%h in (1,1,10) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%g in (' "ping -n 1 1.1.1.%%h | find /i "ttl" "') do (
        if %%g ** *ITSNOTNULL *** (
            set/a counter+=1
            msg * %%g
        )
    )
)
pause>nul
exit
```

Comment: I think you are mistaken.  The code you are using will not output an empty line.

Comment: If `ping` returns output other than a string containing `ttl`, that would be swallowed and thrown away by the `find` command. I would still advise you to throw any errors before piping it however, `"ping -n 1 1.1.1.%%h 2>nul | find /i "ttl""`.

Comment: wasHK, as well as it being a pointless exercise to check for empty content represented by `%%g`, you appear to be incrementing a variable named `counter` and not using it. _Regardless of that fact, in your example, as no value was initially defined for `%counter%`, even taking account of no indication of delayed expansion, its content after `set/a`, will match `%%h` anyhow._ I'm sure that these things my be irrelevant to your actual code, but as you've not really provided actual data I can only comment on the [mcve] you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set counter=0

for /l %%h in (1,1,10) do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%g in (' "ping -n 1 1.1.1.%%h | find /i "ttl" "') do (

        if not "%%g"=="" (

            set /a counter=!counter!+1
            echo * %%g )

        )
)
echo %~NX0 complete.
echo Total IP addresses: %counter%

EndLocal
pause>nul
```

1. Instead of `if %%g ** *ITSNOTNULL ***` I used `if not "%%g"==""`
2. To use a variable within a ***for loop***, if you want to maintain its state, you have to use "DelayedExpansion".  This changes the syntax from `%thingy%` to `!thingy!`.  The reasons for this can be found  [here](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Señor, the OP is incorrect! `%%g` cannot be nul/empty, it must contain at least the case insensitive string `ttl` otherwise it wouldn't reach the `do` portion of the code.

Comment: @Compo.. I don't understand.  I tested it both for hits and misses.  piping the ping into find /i ensures that it will only get lines back containing ttl.  even if it returned an empty line, the "%%g="" would skip it.  I ripped out my "else" statements that I used to test before posting.  Please explain. And sorry if I am being thick!.. it wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: For loops don't return empty `%%variables`; if there's nothing output within the parentheses, the `do` portion is not invoked. But that aside, as I've already stated it doesn't matter what `ping` returns, if there's nothing in it it will not pass the `find` command. Only strings containing the case insensitive substring `ttl` can be represented by `%%g`.

Comment: From my box.. testing it:  Reply from 1.1.1.5: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=54
* Reply from 1.1.1.6: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=54" etc etc etc.  And I wasn't sure about the for loop empty var.. thanks for the tip.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the users `SET /A` syntax.

Comment: This script worked.  I didn't see anyone else post a solution.

Comment: Yes your script works but it absolutely does not need the `IF` comparison. The FOR variable `%%g` will never be NULL.  It will always be populated with data. Take the `IF` comparison out and you will receive exactly the same output. What the OP was describing was never happening so there was no reason for any of us to post any code to fix a NON-EXISTENT problem.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use **`| findstr .`** with operator **`&&`** and **`||`** to check **any character in variable**:

---

```
echo/ %%G or %Any_Variable% | findstr . >nul && (echo/Found something) || (echo/Nothing Found!!)
```

---

```bat
@echo off && SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%L in (1 1 10)do for /f tokens^=* %%G in ('ping -n 1 1.1.1.%%L^|find "TTL"
')do echo/%%~G|findstr .>nul && (echo/ * %%G && set /a "_cnt+=1+0" ) || goto :next

:next
echo/ - %~NX0 complete^^! && echo/ - Total IP addresses: 0!_cnt! & timeout -1 >nul
endlocal & goto :EOF
```